# setTimeout , clearTimeTut

Tags: append, settimeout, cleartimeout

Im new with Jquery and im trying to make something that seems simple but I still can't get it to work.

I want to append a "Hello" to my "body" every second, and I want it to stop after 10sec.

I don't know how to stop the append after 10sec, some help would be welcome.
I must be simple but I cant get my finger on it

```
function Greeting(){
    setTimeout(Greeting, 1000);
 $("body").append("<p> Hello </p>");
    }

Greeting();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Window's [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function () { $('body').append('<p> Hello </p>'); }, 1000);
```

Thanks.